# Help understanding the fundamental system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $$y'=Ay \quad \mathrm{for}\ A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1\\1 &  1\end{pmatrix}$$ How does one compute the real fundamental system? So far I have  computed the sole eigenvalue of $\lambda = 2$ with a multiplicity of 2 and the corresponding eigenvector $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}$. My question is where to go from here? Since the solution will have the form $t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}(u+tv)$ with $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}; u,v \in \mathbb{R^2}$ where do I get my other vector from and how do I solve for the fundamental system?

Comment: You need to get a generalized eigenvector, namely, solve $$At = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are: $$\frac{dy_1}{dx}=3y_1-y_2~~~(1), \frac{dy_2}{dx}=y_1+y_2~~~(2)$$ the repeated eigenvalue o0f $2$, means
$y_1(x)=(A x+B)e^{2x}$ now put this in (1) to get $y_2(x)=(Ax-A+B)e^{2y}.$
$A,B$ can be found by the initial values of $y_1(x_0)$ and $y_2(x_0)$.
The general solution is:
$$y(x)=\begin{pmatrix} ax+b \\ ax-a+b\end{pmatrix} e^{2x}$$